# RFC_READ_TABLE too many columns DATA_BUFFER_EXCEEDED using C#

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I have two DataGridView in the main form and the first one displays data from SAP system and another displays data from Vertica DB, the Function Module I'm using is `RFC_READ_TABLE`, but there's an exception when calling this FM, which is, if there are too many columns in target table (more than 512 characters per row), SAP connector will return an exception:

> DATA_BUFFER_EXCEEDED

Is there any other FMs or ways to retrieving data from SAP without exception?

I figured out a solution, is about split fields into several arrays and store each parts data into a datatable, then merge datatables, but I'm afraid it will cost a lot of time if the row count is too large.

[image: screenshot of the program]

Here comes my code:

```
RfcDestination destination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(cmbAsset.Text);
            readTable = destination.Repository.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");
            /*
             * RFC_READ_TABLE will only extract data up to 512 chars per row. 
             * If you load more data, you will get an DATA_BUFFER_EXCEEDED exception.
             */
            readTable.SetValue("query_table", table);
            readTable.SetValue("delimiter", "~");//Assigns the given string value to the element specified by the given name after converting it appropriately. 
            if (tbRowCount.Text.Trim() != string.Empty) readTable.SetValue("rowcount", tbRowCount.Text);
            t = readTable.GetTable("DATA");
            t.Clear();//Removes all rows from this table. 
            t = readTable.GetTable("FIELDS");
            t.Clear();

            if (selectedCols.Trim() != "" )
            {
                string[] field_names = selectedCols.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                if (field_names.Length > 0)
                {
                    t.Append(field_names.Length);
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string n in field_names)
                    {
                        t.CurrentIndex = i++;
                        t.SetValue(0, n);
                    }
                } 
            }
            t = readTable.GetTable("OPTIONS");
            t.Clear();
            t.Append(1);//Adds the specified number of rows to this table. 
            t.CurrentIndex = 0;
            t.SetValue(0, filter);//Assigns the given string value to the element specified by the given index after converting it appropriately. 

            try
            {
                readTable.Invoke(destination);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
```

Comment: I'd like to nominate this for the Pointless Screenshot Award...

Comment: And since you're not telling us which table you actually read, it's hard to answer...

Comment: ahh, so sorry about the description, the table I need to read is LIPS, LIKP, BKPF, and others, all business data.

Comment: Basically all those Tables are quite large and have a high amount of fields. Your data buffer exceeded means that all the result data delimited by your ~ exceeds the size that the data ROW can hold.  There is not a bypass around this outside of creating a FM to structure your data queries into tables. You need to shave down the amount of columns you are returning to use RFC_READ_TABLE or use other FM's to retrieve data in a more structured manner.

Comment: Thank you, the way I'm using now is: if there are too many fields in target table, I will query all of the fields into a datagrid and let user choose few fields to get data from SAP, I can't create new FM because the account is shared in our project. If there's no better way to merge the partitioned data or get all of the data once for all, I'll keep the old way.

Comment: Ok, just as a fair warning. I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve over all and this might work exactly right for what you are trying to do but I would strongly discourage going to direct table access for reporting anything out of SAP. Particularly if its going to be used to make decisions in your business process.  The tables you mentioned are centered around SD deliveries but there are SOOOO many more tables involved, just take a look at BAPI_DELIVERY_GETLIST FM and see what all its pulling in.  Its not as simple as order header and order item tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should use BBP_READ_TABLE if it is available in your system. This one is better for much reasons. But that is not the point of your question. In RFC_READ_TABLE you have two Imports ROWCOUNT and ROWSKIPS. You have to use them.

I would recommend you a rowcount between 30.000 and 60.000. So you have to execute the RFC several times and each time you increment your ROWSKIPS. First loop: ROWCOUNT=30000 AND ROWSKIPS = 0, Second Loop: ROWCOUNT=30000 AND ROWSKIPS=30000 and so on...

Also be careful of float-fields when using the old RFC_READ_TABLE. There is one in table LIPS. This RFC has problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction

> BAPI

press filter and set to all.
Under Logistics execution you will find deliveries.
The detail screen shows the function name.
Test them directly to find one thats suits then call that function instead of RFC_read_tab.
example:

> BAPI_LIKP_GET_LIST_MSG

Comment: Thank you Phil, let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to have an ABAP RFC function developped to get your datas (with the advantage that you can get a structured / multi table response in one call, and the disadvantage that this is not a standard function / BAPI)